# Custom icons in Compose

Tags: android, vector, icons, drawable, android-jetpack-compose

I have a data class used to dynamically define a menu.

```
data class ActionItemSpec(
    val contentDescription: String,
    val icon: ImageVector,
    val onClick: () -> Unit
)
```

My problem is this works perfectly when using standards Icons but this class problem is it can't take anything else, like a custom drawable.

How do you create an ImageVector from a custom drawable? Can you in Compose?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, for custom icon you can call method *vectorResource()* on **ImageVector** object and pass there id of your vectorAsset.

```
ImageVector.vectorResource(id = R.drawable.myVectorAsset)
```

I had a similar case where I needed to create a custom icon for bottom navigation bar, and this is how I made it:

```
data class BottomNavItem(
    val name: String,
    val route: String,
    val icon: ImageVector
)

BottomNavItem(
    name = getString(R.string.destination_home),
    route = home,
    icon = ImageVector.vectorResource(id = R.drawable.ic_my_home_icon))
```